# Parse find through a join table

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm using Parse and have the following entities..

```
User
----
fullName
```

and

```
Follow
----
follower (User)
followee (User)
```

I'd like to do a find on `Users` with the following criteria.

1. Given some text, their name contains that text.
2. There exists a `Follow` record where they are the `follower` and the current user is the `followee`.

I am currently trying something like this...

```
PFQuery *followQuery = [Follow query];
[followQuery whereKey:@"followee" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
[userQuery whereKey:@"fullName" containsString:theSearchText];

[userQuery whereKey:@"somethingHereButNotSureWhat" matchesQuery:followQuery];
```

Is there a way to get this to work that I'm missing? I don't seem to be able to get the query to work whatever I put in the key. I need to put `self` or `.` or something but nothing I have tried works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the `matchesQuery` on `Follow` class:

```
PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
[userQuery whereKey:@"fullName" containsString:@"SEARCHTEXTHERE"];

PFQuery *followQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Follow"];
[followQuery whereKey:@"followee" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[followQuery whereKey:@"follow" matchesQuery:userQuery];
```

Comment: Yeah. It's not ideal but I did that in the end. The problem is that I want the user objects not the follow objects. This returns an array of follows that I then have to iterate through to get the users out of.

Comment: Yes it returns an array of follows, and by the way you can use `[followQuery includeKey:@"follow"]` so that each follow object includes the user in it. You don't need to do other requests to get the users.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that something like this would work:

```
PFQuery *followQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Follow"];
[followQuery whereKey:@"followee" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

PFQuery *userQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
[userQuery whereKey:@"fullName" containsString:@"SEARCHTEXTHERE"];
[userQuery whereKey:@"USERKEYHERE" matchesKey:followQuery inQuery:followQuery];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: But what is `USERKEYHERE` when it is the user object itself. If I was matching an attribute of user then I could use the key relating to that attribute but I don't know what to put to relate to the actual object itself.